# Why wasn't Hatake Sakumo (Kakashi's father) revived?

Tags: naruto

Kabuto was able to revive almost all high grade shinobi figures. But I was just curious to know why Kabuto didn't revive Kakashi's father.

Kakashi's father, known as Konoha's White Fang, was a renowned, high ranking Konohagakure shinobi. Did Masashi Kishimoto intentionally avoid his ET or was there any specific reason for which Kabuto was unable to revive him?

I am asking this question mainly because Kakashi's father was **mentioned** in many episodes. He was responsible for killing Sasori's parents, which earned him Chiyo's hatred. He was also responsible for Konoha's mission failure for which he took a grave step of committing suicide.

ET's characters like [**Pakura**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Pakura), [**Chukichi**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ch%C5%ABkichi), etc, got resurrected. Although they were not mentioned until the Fourth Shinobi Arc started, their ET were given more importance than Kakashi's father.

Comment: He might just not have found the body! :)

Comment: i beleive his grave is in Konoha village....... it was shown in one of the episodes that Kakashi went at night to his father's grave to pay his respect

Comment: I think it has more to do with the White Fang's strength. He simply wasn't strong as many of the other revived shinobi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It wasn't mentioned anywhere. Kabuto never talked about Sakumo when showing off or discussing his reanimations.

We can only assume:

- They never found a body, or it was so well guarded that Kabuto couldn't get a DNA sample.
- Kabuto was sure of his victory even without Sakumo's DNA, or waited for a right moment to pull him out as a trump card.
- Kabuto is an idiot. (He is, what the hell did he think was going to happen when he revived Madara?!).

Comment: I mean, seriously, why would he even consider reviving you?

Comment: I actually think it was a combination of your first and second bullet points. Sakumo isn't a game changer in terms of strength, and Kabuto takes a risk by trying to fish Sakumo's body out of the Konoha graveyard.

Comment: i deny the Ist point since in one of the episode Kakashi visited his father's grave at night...therefore his body was definately there....so Ist option is out...... other two points are the valid one....

Comment: @Jiraiya The second clause of his first point is pretty effective. Kabuto needs to go into Konoha to get the body, but Konoha is well guarded. Kabuto doesn't want people to figure out his plan, and on top of that, doesn't want to risk failure for such shinobi. This becomes a high risk, yet low reward situation for Kabuto.

Comment: @Jiraiya - Doesn't mean that if a grave is there, the body should be. Kakashi even visited Obito's grave but his body was never there. So the 1st option is still not yet ruled out.

Comment: R.J bhai...... please do share your view points too......

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ and one more thing.....kakshi's father died in his room itself......so there is a high chance that his body could be there in his grave...... therefore and as per my knowlege, itcannot be ruled out....

Answer (score -1):

Sakumo's body was never found like uchiha shisui who committed sucide thats the reason why kabuto coudn't revive sakumo and shisui.

Comment: How do you know this?

Answer (score -1):

Sakumo's body might not have been found by Kabuto, we also know he killed himself so his body could have been damaged badly.

Answer (score -1):

The theory that Sakumo's body was well-guarded in Konoha doesn't hold merit.  Kabuto was able to obtain Sarutobi Asuma and Dan's DNA to resurrect them, what makes you think he couldn't have gotten Sakumo's?

Also, to the one who said Sakumo was not skilled enough... let's not forget that he was on Sannin level.  Unlike Kakashi, he did not need a borrowed Sharingan to kick butt.

My guess is Kichi forgot about Sakumo.

Comment: Your answer is mostly devoted to refuting theories in other answers, and isn't very helpful. Please edit to focus on why you think Kichi forgot about Sakumo.